# JQuery UI not loading without explicit loading of jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this issue, but I can't figure out mine here. I'm trying to load the whole jQuery UI ( Actually I need only the Slider ) and I successed. This is my enqueing which is working:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-google-lib', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.1.4');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.4');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css-google-lib', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

And this is the working various. When I check my head section, I can see I load jquery twice. I read the codex and says that WP loads jquery and jquery UI by default. Why I cannot use them and load them twice? When I remove the jquery enqueueing, jquery UI is not loading. Is it a good practice to load jquery from external sources? Why the wordpress jquery is in version 1.4.1 and google's 2.1.4? When there are these libraries loaded, why can't I use them in the front end? I got quite confused about this.

Comment: See [this article](https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) for some reasons why you shouldn't load your own jQuery. [WordPress includes jQuery as one of its default libraries.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress)

Comment: Maybe you are right, but if I don't load my custom copy of jquery, wordpress is not loading jquery UI. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery and the jQuery UI Slider are both registered by default by WordPress.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) In order to use them, all you should need to do is something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse192997_load_slider' );
function wpse192997_load_slider() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );
}
```

Note, though, that WordPress uses jQuery in `noConflict` mode, which means that the `$` variable used in most jQuery code samples on the Internet won't be available. You can get around that by using the techniques listed [in the *jQuery `noConflict` Wrappers* section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) of the Codex article on [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).